# Signals/slots on non widgets in Qt 5.0

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

As far as the GUI designer, I understand how certain signals affect certain slots and invoke code. Other than that method, I am unsure about how to invoke a slot from a signal.

Take this example:

```
void QFileDialog::directoryEntered ( const QString & directory ) [signal]
```

This is a signal. When the directory is entered, I want this to populate a widget QColumnView with the contents of the directory.

How does a non widget signal invoke a slot of a UI widget.

I assume you use connect but the example provided uses two separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

Signals and slots are features of [QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots). It works well even for non-GUI code.

Connecting a signal to a slot is always done through the `connect` function:

```
connect(myDialog, SIGNAL(directoryEntered(QString)),
    this, SLOT(updateColumn(QString)));
```

here assuming that you have `updateColumn()` slot in your main object handling the actual UI update of that QColumnView.